# PHP: union data from 2 access tables with different column names and order

Tags: php, ms-access-2010

Forgive me for the simplicity of this question but i am pretty new to this.

I have an access file from which till now retrieved data from one table through php and it was working like a charm. Now i have 2 tables in this file and i need to combine the results of the 2 tables in one table (not combine horizontally with same column but consider one blank table filled with results from both tables). Then i need to order this table. I tried with different syntax but failed.

Please give me your lights!

What i tried to do is this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id, Lastname, Firstname, Email FROM `NEW EMPLOYEES`";
$sql .= " UNION SELECT ID, `Last Name`, `First name`, Email FROM `OLD EMPLOYEES`";
$sql .= " ORDER BY Lastname ASC";
?>
```

As you can see i have different column names per column and this does not shows results.

Also, how could i order the results depending on lastname column?In my case from UNION from one table column name is Lastname and from other table same column is `Last Name`.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * from (SELECT id, Lastname, Firstname, Email FROM `NEW EMPLOYEES`";
$sql .= " UNION SELECT ID, `Last Name`, `First name`, Email FROM `OLD EMPLOYEES`) as union_table";
$sql .= " ORDER BY union_table.Lastname ASC";
?>
```

Comment: not working. It does not brings results like its not executing